# How to get all subsets of an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

Given an array: `[dog, cat, mouse]`

what is the most elegant way to create:

```
[,,]
[,,mouse]
[,cat,]
[,cat,mouse]
[dog,,]
[dog,,mouse]
[dog,cat,]
[dog,cat,mouse]
```

I need this to work for any sized array.

This is essentially a binary counter, where array indices represent bits. This presumably lets me use some bitwise operation to count, but I can't see a nice way of translating this to array indices though.

Comment: None of the answers seem to have the elegance you are looking for, what while you wait for an answer, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679203/how-to-find-all-possible-subsets-of-a-given-array

Comment: All subsets of a set S == the 'power set' of S.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 string[] source = new string[] { "dog", "cat", "mouse" };
 for (int i = 0; i < Math.Pow(2, source.Length); i++)
 {
     string[] combination = new string[source.Length];
     for (int j = 0; j < source.Length; j++)
     {
         if ((i & (1 << (source.Length - j - 1))) != 0)
         {
             combination[j] = source[j];
         }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}, {1}, {2}]", combination[0], combination[1], combination[2]);
}
```

Comment: The question explicitly mentions: "given any sized array."

Comment: Updated to a more generalized version.

Comment: Chose this as its concise and to the point, also probably more efficient than Linq or List<>s

Comment: "Probably" in this instance being short for "I'm too lazy to measure it."

Comment: This wont work if I add one more string in the source. as you have used only 3 combination for output.

Comment: Why is this the answer? This doesn't generate what the OP is asking for, it uses repetition, e.g., [dog, dog, dog].

Answer (score 40):

Elegant?  Why not Linq it.

```
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SubSetsOf<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        if (!source.Any())
            return Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Empty<T>(), 1);

        var element = source.Take(1);

        var haveNots = SubSetsOf(source.Skip(1));
        var haves = haveNots.Select(set => element.Concat(set));

        return haves.Concat(haveNots);
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `BitArray` class to easily access the bits in a number:

```
string[] animals = { "Dog", "Cat", "Mouse" };
List<string[]> result = new List<string[]>();
int cnt = 1 << animals.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
   string[] item = new string[animals.Length];
   BitArray b = new BitArray(i);
   for (int j = 0; j < item.Length; j++) {
      item[j] = b[j] ? animals[j] : null;
   }
   result.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Code snippet throws `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` exception.

Comment: I think you must initalize as BitArray b = new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(i)); for not getting RangeException error.

Answer (score 7):

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetSubsets<T>(IList<T> set)
{
    var state = new BitArray(set.Count);
    do
        yield return Enumerable.Range(0, state.Count)
                               .Select(i => state[i] ? set[i] : default(T));
    while (Increment(state));
}

static bool Increment(BitArray flags)
{
    int x = flags.Count - 1; 
    while (x >= 0 && flags[x]) flags[x--] = false ;
    if (x >= 0) flags[x] = true;
    return x >= 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach(var strings in GetSubsets(new[] { "dog", "cat", "mouse" }))
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", strings.ToArray()));
```

Comment: That's the answer I would write if I knew C#! But it still could  be made nicer with a small change to how Increment works. I'll post it below, because it won't fit into comment.

Comment: I wrote the optimization below :)

Comment: The value of "state" is captured, but by the time the .Select(i => state[i] ...   is executed state is all zeros.  Need to add a .ToList() after the Select

Comment: @innominate227 You are right about `state` being captured, but it does not make a difference here, as `BitArray` is a reference type anyway. Even if it were not captured, `state` would have referred to the same instance which always be the updated copy with `Increment`.

Answer (score 6):

Guffa's answer had the basic functionality that I was searching, however the line with

```
BitArray b = new BitArray(i);
```

did not work for me, it gave an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Here's my slightly adjusted and working code:

```
string[] array = { "A", "B", "C","D" };
int count = 1 << array.Length; // 2^n

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    string[] items = new string[array.Length];
    BitArray b = new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(i));
    for (int bit = 0; bit < array.Length; bit++) {
        items[bit] = b[bit] ? array[bit] : "";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("",items));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easy-to-follow solution along the lines of your conception:

```
private static void Test()
{
    string[] test = new string[3] { "dog", "cat", "mouse" };

    foreach (var x in Subsets(test))
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(",", x));
}

public static IEnumerable<T[]> Subsets<T>(T[] source)
{
    int max = 1 << source.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        T[] combination = new T[source.Length];

        for (int j = 0; j < source.Length; j++)
        {
            int tailIndex = source.Length - j - 1;
            combination[tailIndex] =
                ((i & (1 << j)) != 0) ? source[tailIndex] : default(T);
        }

        yield return combination;
    }
}
```

Comment: The || source.Length == 0 shouldn't really be there: subsets of empty set exist. If you erase that, it will correctly return empty set.

Comment: Can you please add comments to explain these expressions: 
`1 << source.Length`               `((i & (1 << j)) != 0)`
How does it work?

Comment: @ilyan. Can you please add comments to explain these lines: `1 << source.Length` and  `((i & (1 << j)) != 0)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution similar to David B's method, but perhaps more suitable if it's really a requirement that you get back sets with the original number of elements (even if empty):.

```
static public List<List<T>> GetSubsets<T>(IEnumerable<T> originalList)
{
    if (originalList.Count() == 0)
        return new List<List<T>>() { new List<T>() };

    var setsFound = new List<List<T>>();
    foreach (var list in GetSubsets(originalList.Skip(1)))
    {                
        setsFound.Add(originalList.Take(1).Concat(list).ToList());
        setsFound.Add(new List<T>() { default(T) }.Concat(list).ToList());
    }
    return setsFound;
}
```

If you pass in a list of three strings, you'll get back eight lists with three elements each (but some elements will be null).

Answer (score 1):

This is a small change to Mehrdad's solution above:

```
static IEnumerable<T[]> GetSubsets<T>(T[] set) {
    bool[] state = new bool[set.Length+1];
    for (int x; !state[set.Length]; state[x] = true ) {
        yield return Enumerable.Range(0, state.Length)
                               .Where(i => state[i])
                               .Select(i => set[i])
                               .ToArray();
        for (x = 0; state[x]; state[x++] = false);
    }
}
```

or with pointers

```
static IEnumerable<T[]> GetSubsets<T>(T[] set) {
    bool[] state = new bool[set.Length+1];
    for (bool *x; !state[set.Length]; *x = true ) {
        yield return Enumerable.Range(0, state.Length)
                               .Where(i => state[i])
                               .Select(i => set[i])
                               .ToArray();
        for (x = state; *x; *x++ = false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>I'm not very familiar with C# but I'm sure there's something like:</s>

```
// input: Array A
foreach S in AllSubsetsOf1ToN(A.Length): 
    print (S.toArray().map(lambda x |> A[x]));
```

---

Ok, I've been told the answer above won't work. If you value **elegance over efficiency**, I would try recursion, in my crappy pseudocode:

```
Array_Of_Sets subsets(Array a) 
{
    if (a.length == 0) 
         return [new Set();] // emptyset
    return subsets(a[1:]) + subsets(a[1:]) . map(lambda x |> x.add a[0]) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variant of mqp's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/999102/11178549), that uses as state a [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger) instead of an `int`, to avoid overflow for collections containing more than 30 elements:

```
using System.Numerics;

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetSubsets<T>(IList<T> source)
{
    BigInteger combinations = BigInteger.One << source.Count;
    for (BigInteger i = 0; i < combinations; i++)
    {
        yield return Enumerable.Range(0, source.Count)
            .Select(j => (i & (BigInteger.One << j)) != 0 ? source[j] : default);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy to understand version (with descriptions)

I assumed that source = {1,2,3,4}

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetSubSets<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        var result = new List<IEnumerable<T>>() { new List<T>() }; // empty cluster  added

        for (int i = 0; i < source.Count(); i++)
        {
            var elem = source.Skip(i).Take(1);

            // for elem = 2
            // and currently result = [ [],[1] ]
            var matchUps = result.Select(x => x.Concat(elem));
            //then matchUps => [ [2],[1,2] ]

             result = result.Concat(matchUps).ToList();
            //  matchUps and result concat operation
            // finally result = [ [],[1],[2],[1,2] ]
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    List<int[]> subsets = new List<int[]>() { new int[] {} };
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
            foreach (var item in subsets.ToList())
            {

                subsets.Add(item.Concat(new int[] { arr[i] }).ToArray());
            }    
    }
    foreach(var item in subsets)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", item));
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The way this is written, it is more of a Product (Cartesian product) rather than a list of all subsets.

You have three sets: `(Empty,"dog"), (Empty,"cat"),(Empty,"mouse")`.

There are several posts on general solutions for products. As noted though, since you really just have 2 choices for each axis a single bit can represent the presence or not of the item.

So the total set of sets is all numbers from `0` to `2^N-1`. If `N < 31` an int will work.