# Algorithm to return all combinations for array of lines

Tags: .net, vb.net, algorithm

**Task**
Get all combinations for array (array is very simple 1,2,3,4,5 - just indexes of lines in table, always in order, so we can use just count-number)

I need result looks like : List of array or List Of List (0:0, 1:1, 2:0,1, 3:3, 4: 0,1,2 ...)

**Data state**
I have rows in table, each row contains 6 columns with decimal number.
My target to get sum of numbers from that columns for each selected row which closest to my specific number(test say 600). So I have to select only that rows what have the closet number in sum.

**Code**

1. cyclical

   ```
   Private Function CreateSubsets(Of T)(ByVal originalArray() As T) As List(Of T())

   Dim subsets As New List(Of T())

   For i As Integer = 0 To originalArray.Length - 1

       Dim subsetCount As Integer = subsets.Count
       subsets.Add(New T() {originalArray(i)})

       For j As Integer = 0 To subsetCount - 1
           Dim newSubset(subsets(j).Length) As T
           subsets(j).CopyTo(newSubset, 0)
           newSubset(newSubset.Length - 1) = originalArray(i)
           subsets.Add(newSubset)
       Next

   Next

   Return subsets
   End Function
   ```
2. recursive

   ```
   Private Function GetAllCombos(Of T)(ByVal list As List(Of T)) As List(Of List(Of T))

   Dim result As List(Of List(Of T)) = New List(Of List(Of T))
   'head
   result.Add(New List(Of T))
   result.Last().Add(list(0))

   If (list.Count = 1) Then
       Return result
   End If

   'tail
   Dim tailCombos = GetAllCombos(list.Skip(1).ToList())
   tailCombos.ForEach(Sub(combo)
                          result.Add(New List(Of T)(combo))
                          combo.Add(list(0))
                          result.Add(New List(Of T)(combo))
                      End Sub)
   Return result

   End Function
   ```

**Problems**

Get the axception "System.OutOfMemoryException" in both cases.
How can I avoid this problem, any solutions? Maybe someone had the same task. I cannot disable limit for large objects - *system .NET Framework 4.0 32bit*

Comment: The complexity of the function you're trying to do is a factorial of the amount of elements in your array, so for 5 elements it's 5!=120 combinations, for 10 elements it's already 10!=3628800 combinations. How many elements are actually in your array?

Comment: For now it works  for <=25 items, but I need more, it can be 100 items

Comment: Assuming a list only takes 10 bytes of RAM (hint: it's more) then you would need more megabytes of RAM than there are atoms in the universe. It's not possible. (100!=9.332622e+157, that's a 9 with 157 zeros of possible permutations)

Comment: I really don't think that problem in RAM, I have a lot. Problem in limit for objects.

Comment: However you can happily enumerate the combinations all day [eternity] long if you use a lazy iterator...  Take a step back, WHY do you think you want ALL the combinations?

Comment: You right, for now I will go to split items into groups and work with groups. But it is not the best solution. I need combinations because I colculate for each one possible result(delta value), after that I select only linel with the lowest delta - so I need indexes of lines for selecting it.

Comment: Based on your example (result looks like) I have a hard time figuring out if you actually want all possible combinations (eg. 1,2,3 -> {(1,2,3),(1,3,2),(2,1,3),(2,3,1),(3,1,2),(3,2,1)}) or something else. If it's all possible combinations you're looking for you absolutely have to use a different approach (eg. loop through all possibilities but only store it if the delta is less than the previously stored delta).

Comment: @Longoon12000 I _think_ he is genuinely interested in combinations not permutations, in his example thats actually ~ subsets.  That means it's !ONLY! (2^n) - 1 items he has to worry about, your points still very much stand though

Comment: @tolanj It is possible, do you know algorithm for it? I wondering because for calculation combinations the method uses prev list combinations as base. How can I do it in different way? Each number in combinations mean index of row - from the row I can calculate a delta.

Comment: The problem remains,  you _say_ you want all the combinations of elements, ie all the subsets of the array.  However if there are 100 items in the array there are 2^100 subsets.  This is more than a 64 bit address space, if you calculated each of these at one millisec per calc it would take ~10^20 years etc etc

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10374521/2701753 shows a nice enough method for actually enumerating the subsets, combine that with a Yield statement to make a lazy iterator and, well, you wont run out of memory, _but you will run out of time_  If you say why you think you need to do this we might actually be able to help

Comment: @tolanj Thank you for link with answer - I will try to re-implement it for my case. I added details for my task, take a look please on top of qtn. And sorry for my bad English)

Comment: With your addition of details I get what you are trying to do.  Brute force is not the answer.  Do you only care about one column at a time OR do you need to optimise across several cpulums at once?

Comment: @tolanj several columns, I calculate a delta velue for it from all 6 columns

Comment: Okay so, implementation details aside this is a decimal version of the  0-1 knapsack problem.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem, perhaps with an added complication that the numbers can be negative?  I would reask the question in those terms

Comment: @tolanj I saw solution for knapsack. not sure that it is the same like my task. I need to get list of row indexes, delta only for comparing, (I dont need it in result) There is no negative values (always >= 0)