# Find elements in a list that, together add up to a target number

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have a list:

```
List<int> _arr = new List<int> {1, 3, 4};
```

And a target of `4`

I want to return `{1, 3}` as `1 + 3 = 4` and `{4}` as `4 = 4` using linq from the given list.

How do I do that?

Comment: Question is not clear !!!

Comment: Suppose I have list as mentioned above.

And i was given a number a = 4

Now I need to find all set of numbers whose sum is equal to to a.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to find combinations of numbers in a list that add up to a target number? Correct?

Comment: What if you have list `{1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5}` ? And what you have tried so far?

Comment: Should it look for every possible combination which is 4?

Comment: You want to find a combination of numbers inside `_arr` such that the sum of those numbers equals to `a`, is that it? Unfortunately, I don't think Linq is the best solution. Better try *Dynamic Programming*

Comment: Do you only want "groups" of 1 or 2 elements? or you could have a "group" having more than 2 elements? eg. {1,2,1} or {1,1,1,1}

Comment: Just because there is a collection involved doesn't mean LINQ is the best way. Even if this could be done in LINQ I bet the implementation would be horribly unreadable.

Comment: Weyland if this is the situation then do suggest some other solution, i want to know whether linq is capable to handle the situation or not and if not then what is the best bet other than looping

Comment: @WeylandYutani: I don't think it's too bad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's easy once we have a method to get all subsets of an enumerator/list
(found here: [Answer: Most Elegant Way to Get All Subsets of an Array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/999182/593627))

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

        var target = 6;

        var matches = from subset in test.SubSetsOf()
                      where subset.Sum() == target
                      select subset;

        Console.WriteLine("Numbers: {0}", test.Select(i => i.ToString()).Aggregate((a, n) => a + ", " + n));
        Console.WriteLine("Target: {0}", target);

        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Select(m => m.ToString()).Aggregate((a, n) => a + " + " + n) + " = " + target.ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SubSetsOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        // Deal with the case of an empty source (simply return an enumerable containing a single, empty enumerable)
        if (!source.Any())
            return Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Empty<T>(), 1);

        // Grab the first element off of the list
        var element = source.Take(1);

        // Recurse, to get all subsets of the source, ignoring the first item
        var haveNots = SubSetsOf(source.Skip(1));

        // Get all those subsets and add the element we removed to them
        var haves = haveNots.Select(set => element.Concat(set));

        // Finally combine the subsets that didn't include the first item, with those that did.
        return haves.Concat(haveNots);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
Target: 6
1 + 2 + 3 = 6
1 + 5 = 6
2 + 4 = 6
6 = 6
```

Comment: Can you please explain the subset method?

Comment: I've added comments, it helps to think about what happens with a set containing a single element, then one containing 2.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution to this problem, is [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Create a 2-Dimensional Array, with dimensions [a + 1, _arr.Length]:

```
  0 1 2 3 4
1
3
4
```

Then, for each column in that 2D array, fill in each cell, such that the sum of all cells of a column equals to the index of the column:

```
  0 1 2 3 4
1 0 1 x 0 1
3 0 0 x 1 1
4 0 0 x 0 0

// Alternative solution
  0 1 2 3 4
1 0 1 x 0 0
3 0 0 x 1 0
4 0 0 x 0 1
```

Here, `x` means, there is no solution. Also, column 4 has 2 solutions, so you need to account for that, maybe with a `List<int>[a]`?

As to how to fill in those cells *exactly*:
Column `0` will hold all zeroes, because it's a solution that can be achieved without a sum.
For Column `i`, you want to do `i - n` (where `n` is the current number from _arr)

```
  0 1
1 0 1   // 1 - 1 == 0, so you put 1 in here
3 0 0
4 0 0

  0 1 2
1 0 1 x // 2 - 1 == 1, 1 already has a solution, but you already used the number necessary to solve 1
3 0 0 x
4 0 0 x
```

If you had more than one `1`s

```
  0 1 2
1 0 1 1 //             1 - 1 == 0
1 0 0 1 // 2 - 1 == 1, 1 already has a solution
3 0 0 0
4 0 0 0

// Alternative solution
  0 1 2
1 0 0 1 // 2 - 1 == 1, 1 already has a solution
1 0 1 1 //             1 - 1 == 0
3 0 0 0
4 0 0 0
```

If you need more information on dynamic programming: [Knapsack Problem Dynamic Programming Algorithm](http://www.programminglogic.com/knapsack-problem-dynamic-programming-algorithm/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that using a simple LINQ query. In fact, I'm having a hard time coming up with a simple solution for this using full-blown T-SQL!

The problem is you're trying to return not single items, but various collections of items based on possible permutations.

On that note, I do hope someone comes up with such a LINQ query, cos something tells me it would will be awesome. ;)

Comment: "I do hope someone comes up with such a LINQ query, cos something tells me it would will be awesome" Well now I have to try!

Comment: Personally, I think T-SQL is terrible for this kind of problem.  But that's just me.

Comment: @Moo-Juice LINQ is (to me at least) a simplified query language. T-SQL is a 'full' query language, thus my reference. I also think it's not the best tool for this problem, but the OP did state he's looking for a LINQ query...

Answer (score 1):

If you are after a really good and fast solution to this problem you are not alone.

This is a well know SUBSET SUM problem. I suggest you could look it up at Wikipedia here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Of course you could iterate through all possible subsets looking for your sum but be aware that there is (2 ^ CountOfListElements) possible combinations. If the list is always small in size you will have no problems coding it. Even exponential time solution will work for small sets.