# Best algorithm for finding the combination of a word?

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find all possible subsets of a given array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679203/how-to-find-all-possible-subsets-of-a-given-array)

so say you have

ab

you can have a,b,ab

whats the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

From the [`itertools recipes`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

This is a standard python module, so reading that should give you insights on how its implemented and what algorithm is used. I don't know if it is the best, but it's an algorithm from the real world.

Answer (score 0):

[A power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) is one solution

> Power set of a set A is the set whose
>   members are all possible subsets of A.
>   For example, the powerset of {1, 2} is
>   { {}, {1}, {2}, {1,2} } .

There's a Python solution:

> [What algorithm can calculate the power set of a given set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779094/what-algorithm-can-calculate-the-power-set-of-a-given-set)