# How do I find the closest possible sum of an Array's elements to a particular value?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

In Java, how should I find the closest (or equal) possible sum of an Array's elements to a particular value K?

For example, for the array {19,23,41,5,40,36} and K=44, the closest possible sum is 23+19=42.
I've been struggling on this for hours; I know almost nothing about dynamic programming. By the way, the array contains only positive numbers.

Comment: This is a fair question, but probably more suited here: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Wouldn't 5 + 40 be the closest possible sum?

Comment: I meant that the sum would be under or equal to K

Comment: Is there a limit of numbers you can add up? For example, can you only use two elements per sum, or could you also use the sum over all elements?

Comment: The sum over any number of elements

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: get all the possible subsets of your array as in the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640034/calculating-all-of-the-subsets-of-a-set-of-numbers   and they loop over the sets and choose the set with the maximum sum that is below or equal to k. not optimal algorithm but it will work if that is not an issue here.

Comment: Calculating all subsets may literally take for years, depending on the size of his array.

Comment: i mentioned if it is not an issue here. so definately it will depend on his input

Comment: @A.J. You mean something like the solurion I provided below? G.Back, there are problems that take years, unfortunately, maybe this belongs to this category.

Comment: @zafeiris.m yes looks similar to your solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You would typically use dynamic programming for such a problem. However, that essentially boils down to keeping a set of possible sums and adding the input values one by one, as in the following code, and has the same asymptotic running time: `O(n K)`, where `n` is the size of your input array and `K` is the target value.

The constants in the version below are probably bigger, however, but I think the code is much easier to follow, than the dynamic programming version would be.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int K = 44;
        List<Integer> inputs = Arrays.asList(19,23,41,5,40,36);

        int opt = 0;                // optimal solution so far          

        Set<Integer> sums = new HashSet<>();
        sums.add(opt);

        // loop over all input values
        for (Integer input : inputs) {
            Set<Integer> newSums = new HashSet<>();

            // loop over all sums so far                        
            for (Integer sum : sums) {
                int newSum = sum + input;

                // ignore too big sums
                if (newSum <= K) {
                    newSums.add(newSum);

                    // update optimum                       
                    if (newSum > opt) {
                        opt = newSum;
                    }
                }
            }

            sums.addAll(newSums);
        }

        System.out.println(opt);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

A short note on running time might be useful, since I just claimed `O(n K)` without justification.

Clearly, initialization and printing the result just takes constant time, so we should analyse the double loop.

The outer loop runs over all inputs, so it's body is executed `n` times.

The inner loop runs over all sums so far, which could be an exponential number in theory. *However*, we use an upper bound of `K`, so all values in `sums` are in the range `[0, K]`. Since `sums` is a set, it contains at most `K+1` elements.

All computations inside the inner loop take constant time, so the total loop takes `O(K)`. The set `newSums` also contains at most `K+1` elements, for the same reason, so the `addAll` in the end takes `O(K)` as well.

Wrapping up: the outer loop is executed `n` times. The loop body takes `O(K)`. Therefore, the algorithm runs in `O(n K)`.

**EDIT 2**

Upon request on how to also find the elements that lead to the optimal sum:

Instead of keeping track of a single integer - the sum of the sublist - you should also keep track of the sublist itself. This is relatively straightforward if you create a new type (no getters/setters to keep the example concise):

```
public class SubList {
    public int size;
    public List<Integer> subList;

    public SubList() {
        this(0, new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public SubList(int size, List<Integer> subList) {
        this.size = size;
        this.subList = subList;
    }
}
```

The initialization now becomes:

```
SubList opt = new SubList();

Set<SubList> sums = new HashSet<>();
sums.add(opt);
```

The inner loop over the `sums` needs some small adaptations as well:

```
for (Integer input : inputs) {
    Set<SubList> newSums = new HashSet<>();

    // loop over all sums so far                        
    for (SubList sum : sums) {
        List<Integer> newSubList = new ArrayList<>(sum.subList);
        newSubList.add(input);
        SubList newSum = new SubList(sum.size + input, newSubList);         

        // ignore too big sums
        if (newSum.size <= K) {
            newSums.add(newSum);

            // update optimum                       
            if (newSum.size > opt) {
                opt = newSum;
            }
        }
    }

    sums.addAll(newSums);
}
```

Comment: I read your solution and try to understand, maybe my question is stupid, but I can see where you *add* a number in the final solution, what I don't see is where you exclude a number of the final solution. I would expect that, at some point, you should realise that a included number should be excluded to lead to a better solution, isn't it?

Comment: @zafeiris.m I only keep track of the sums, not of the values they are composed off. Basically, after iteration `i` of the outer loop (over `inputs`), the set `sums` contains *all* possible sums that can be made with the first `i` input values. To make sure that the size of that set doesn't grow exponentially, I added `upperBound`, which makes sure `sums` contains at most `2*K` values.

Comment: but what if the best solution does not include the first `i` elements, but, say, the 1st, the 4th, and the 6th?

Comment: This is good but I want the sum to never be larger than K. Getting the closest sum that's smaller or equal to K.

Comment: @zafeiris.m ok, let's run a small example... assume `inputs={3,2,4}` and `K=8`. Clearly, 7 is the optimal solution, by picking the 1st and the 3rd input. We start with `sums={0}`. In the first iteration of the outer loop, we pick the 1st input (3), add it to all sums so far, and add the result back in `sums`, hence `sums={0, 3}`. In the second iteration, we do the same for 2, hence `sums={0,2,3,5}`. Finally, we add 4 and get `sums={0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9}`. The best solution, 7, is in the set, even though it 'skipped' the 2nd input.

Comment: @Heuster Thank you, I can see it now, nice solution! But what I don't understand is the worst case complexity. In the example of your comment (and in any example that most of the elements will be included in the result), I see the result set gets doubled everytime, resulting in **exponential** complexity, isn't it? Tell me if I'm wrong. *Update*: Also space complexity is exponential since you keep each sub-result, right?

Comment: @zafeiris.m I added a note on running time. The trick is in `upperBound`, which keeps the size of `sums` linear in `K`.

Comment: @zafeiris.m There likely is not a polynomial-time algorithm since this is an NP-Complete problem.

Comment: @Paulpro well, it's weakly NP-complete, so as long as `K` is polynomial in `n`, the algorithm will run in polynomial time.

Comment: @Paulpro absolutely! But on the other hand, in this implementation, `K` is an integer, so it's size is at most `MAX_INT`, which is a (rather big) constant, so the running time is just `O(n)` ;-)

Comment: isn't this just a bruteforce or kind of DP ? sorry , i don't understand java .

Comment: @anon A brute force would try all `2^n` sums, whereas this algorithm runs in `O(n K)` time, so no, this is no brute force.

Comment: @Heuster: another question : the required sequence cannot be generated . Am i right ? if No , kindly explain that approach .

Comment: @anon I updated the answer with a witnessing approach: whenever you update the optimum, you also keep track of the sublist that led to that optimum.

Comment: How can this code compile? The adaptation code is using sum and sums in both inner and outer loop. Does it require an update? I am trying to adapt the subList example, but not working as it says "Duplicate Variable" "sum" and "sums"

Comment: @YogendraJ there was clearly a typo in the second example, this is fixed now. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: As I am more comfortable with JavaScript, I have converted this here https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/jf1ucyxg/ Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 2):

You can see it as a `n-choose-k` problem for all possible `k` so the complexity [is exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations_for_all_k).

1. Find a set of numbers that sum at most up to `K`. The set should include `i` numbers, for `i=1; i<=N; i++`. To implement this, for each `i` just take all the `n-choose-i` [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of the numbers in the array.
2. Keep a `finalResult` variable with the best set of numbers found so far and their sum.
3. Compare each sub-result of step 1 with the `finalResult` and update it if necessary.

It reminds me of the [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), so you may want to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

```
private int closestSum(int[] a, int num){
    int k=a.length-1;
    int sum=0;
    Arrays.sort(a);

    while(a[k]>num){
        k--;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<=k;j++){
            if(a[i]+a[j]<=num && a[i]+a[j]>sum)
                sum = a[i]+a[j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say first sort the array. Then your example would be: arr = {5, 19, 23, 36, 40, 41}.
Then:
1) Take arr[0] and arr[i], where i = arr.Size. Sum it and record the difference between the sum and K, if the sum is lower than K.
2) If sum > K, do step 1, but instead of arr[i], use arr[i-1], because we want to lower our sum.
   If sum < K, do step 1, but instead of arr[0], use arr[1], because we want to increase our sum.
   Keep repeating step2, by either increasing or decreasing the indices, until the indices for the two elements are equal. 
Then, we know the pair of elements that result in the smallest difference between the sum and K.

----------------Edited for arbitrary number of elements in the solution----------------

I believe you may need a tree.  Here's what I'm thinking:

1) Choose a number as your top node.

2) For each number in the set, create a child node, and for each branch that was created,
   calculate the sum of that branch.

3) If the sum is less then K, we branch again, creating child nodes for all the elements in the set. If the sum is greater than K, we stop, keep the difference between the sum and K(If sum < K). If we find a branch with a better sum, then we keep that branch. Repeat this process until all branches are done branching.

Do steps 1-3 with different topnodes.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this will not solve his problem correctly; take for example [1, 2, 10] searching for 13.

Comment: @Calpis, but what about more than two numbers participating in the result?

Comment: O sorry, I didn't realize it was an arbitrary number for the solution..Let me rethink this