# Find out all possible combinations in a arraylist : java

Tags: java, arraylist, combinations

I would like to know how to calculate all possible combinations in a given arraylist?
E.g

ArrayList contains following elements `{1, 2, 3}`. now the following combinations should be generated

```
{1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3}, {1,2,3}
```

Comment: Is `{}` one of the combinations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating all of the subsets of a set of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640034/calculating-all-of-the-subsets-of-a-set-of-numbers)

Comment: You'll have more luck searching for an answer using the words _set_, _[power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set)_ and _all subsets_. All permutations of a list is all possible arrangements of its elements. And note that a power set would include the empty set. [Here's](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power%5FSet#Java) some Java code if you want to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

you can try [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [Sets#powerSet](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#powerSet%28java.util.Set%29)

`Sets.powerSet(Sets.newHashSet(<your list>))`

Answer (score 1):

You can see each element in array list as  a bit and implement a binary counter . The count gives you all the sets . You have 1, 2 ,3 in arraylist , lets visualize them as 3 bits for a while .
000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110,111 gives you the power set. All you need to is implement a binary counter , which is trivial.

Comment: I like this one. And you've definitely deserved your first upvote