# Using distinct binary numbers to find subsets of a given set

Tags: javascript, java, c#, algorithm, big-o

So the challenge is to design an algorithm that PRINTS the subsets of a given set `n`.

Let's set n equal:

```
 n = {a,b,c}
```

On this [stack overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640034/calculating-all-of-the-subsets-of-a-set-of-numbers) there is an answer from @Piva that solves this problem using the fact that "Each number from 0 to 2^n gives a unique subset in its binary representation"

I have written a Javascript version of @Piva's code, it works well. I understand most of it except one line:

```
if(((i>>j) & 1) === 1)
```

I think I understand this line of code is shifting i bits right, adding j zeros to the beginning of i's binary representation. I also understand the bit wise & is comparing i >>j to 1 and seeing if the first bit is on from the output i >>.

But I don't understand how this operation identifies unique binary representations and why the `if(((i>>j) & 1) === 1)` being true means we have a unique subset of a given `n`.

Here is my Javascript version:

```
    function SubsetBuilder(set) {
        this.set = set;

    }

    SubsetBuilder.prototype.getSubsets = function () {
        var self = this;

        if (!self.set)
            return null;

        //recursive way, do next
        var getSubsetsAll = function (originalSet) {
            if (!originalSet) {
                return;
            }
        }

        var n = this.set.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < (1<<n); i++) {
            var subset = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                console.log('i:' + i + ", binary: " + i.toString(2));
                console.log('j:' + j + ", binary: " + j.toString(2));
                console.log('(i >> j):');
                console.log((i >> j));
                console.log('((i>>j) & 1):');
                console.log(((i >> j) & 1));
                if(((i>>j) & 1) === 1){ // bit j is on
                    subset.push(this.set[j]);
                }
                console.log('-------------------');
            }
            console.log(subset);
            console.log('-------------------');
        }
    }

    var set = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    var obj = new SubsetBuilder(set);
    obj.getSubsets();
```

Comment: I've added a comment to respond to your question on the answer. I don't feel this warrants a completely new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if(((i>>j) & 1) === 1)` checks if the j-th bit of i is set.

To understand how this works, consider the number 5 in binary 101b.
`>>` is just a shift (or equivalently, division by 2<sup>n</sup>) and `& 1` masks out all but the least significant bit.

```
(101b >> 0) & 1 = (101b & 1) = 1
(101b >> 1) & 1 = ( 10b & 1) = 0
(101b >> 2) & 1 = (  1b & 1) = 1
```

So once wen understand how the bit-extraction works, we need to understand why bit-extraction is equivalent to subset inclusion:

Here's how we map from binary numbers 0-7 to subsets of {A,B,C}

```
0: 0 0 0   => {     }
1: 0 0 1   => {    A}
2: 0 1 0   => {  B  }
3: 0 1 1   => {  B A}
4: 1 0 0   => {C    }
5: 1 0 1   => {C   A}
6: 1 1 0   => {C B  }
7: 1 1 1   => {C B A}
```

And clearly we have listed all subsets.

Hopefully you can now see why the test for the j-th bit of i is equivalent to the inclusion of the j-th object into the ith subset.

Comment: Ok, I am getting there, I worry that it is taking me so long to grasp this though I have been writing code for almost 20 years lol. So I am getting that a bitmask is a way to "mark" subsets of set n. I am seeing now, thanks to your answer that if(((i>>j) & 1) === 1) is checking if the j-th bit of i is "ON" and i is a bitmask that marks a point, with a binary 1 where we have a unique subset.

A couple things I would like to be clearer on, the operator >> in particular. I understand what 1<<n is doing and I can picture the binary notation and shift of that, but I am having trouble with i >> j

Comment: Would I read i >> j as the following, "add j zeros to the beginning of the binary notation of i"?

Comment: Made it clearer what each of the operators is doing in the description.

Comment: Awesome answer, you the man^n lol. One last question if you could be so kind, why does i iterator 2^n-1 and not 2^n, I know that I can "build S(n) by cloning S(n-1) and adding n to the cloned sets but I am still having trouble picturing why its S(n-1) for i

Comment: Never mind, for the set {a,b,c} i is iterating 8 times, I thought it was for seven for a minute there