# How to concatenate all cases of word presentation in a sentence JAVA

Tags: java, string, concatenation, permutation

**Input:** list of n words "**word1 word2 word3...wordn**"

**Output:** list of strings in concatenation of all cases of permutation presentation as:

```
s1: "word1 word2"
s2: "word1 word3"
s3: "word2 word1"
s4: "word2 word3"
s5: "word3 word1"
s6: "word3 word1"
s7: "word1 word2 word3"
s8: "word1 word3 word2"
s9: "word2 word1 word3"
s10: "word2 word3 word1"
s11: "word3 word1 word2"
s12: "word3 word2 word1"
...
sm: "wordn...word3 word 2 word 1"
```

I try this code:

```
    public static List<String> PermuteWords(String s){
        String[] ss = s.split(" ");
        boolean[] used = new boolean[ss.length];
        String res = "";
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        permute(ss, used, res, 0, list);
        return list;
    }

    private static void permute(String[] ss, boolean[] used, 
        String res, int level, List<String> list) {

        if (level == ss.length && res != ""){
            list.add(res);
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
            if (used[i]) {
                continue;
            }
            used[i] = true;
            permute(ss, used, res + " " + ss[i], level + 1, list);
            used[i] = false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        String inputString="word1 word2 word3";
        List<String> test=PermuteWords(inputString);

        for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(test.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
 word1 word2 word3
 word1 word3 word2
 word2 word1 word3
 word2 word3 word1
 word3 word1 word2
 word3 word2 word1
```

However it is missing some cases as:

```
s1: "word1 word2"
s2: "word1 word3"
s3: "word2 word1"
s4: "word2 word3"
s5: "word3 word1"
s6: "word3 word1"
```

Does anyone can solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating all of the subsets of a set of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640034/calculating-all-of-the-subsets-of-a-set-of-numbers)

Comment: @PM 77-1 it is different, because that did not solve the problem all cases of permutation in words as " word1<->word2" and "word2<->word1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
private static void permute(String[] ss, boolean[] used,
                            String res, int level, List<String> list) {

    // End case
    if (level == ss.length && res != ""){
        list.add(res);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
        // Check if the string is currently used
        if (used[i]) {
            continue;
        }
        // Check if res is empty or a single word
        if(level > 1)
            list.add(res);
        used[i] = true;
        permute(ss, used, res + " " + ss[i], level + 1, list);
        used[i] = false;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 word1 word2
 word1 word2 word3
 word1 word3
 word1 word3 word2
 word2 word1
 word2 word1 word3
 word2 word3
 word2 word3 word1
 word3 word1
 word3 word1 word2
 word3 word2
 word3 word2 word1
```

The problem with the code I believe is that elements were added to the list only when the recursion reached the end, not allowing subelements like you wanted.

Comment: Yeah, thanks you. It is good. I ran your code, but It still has duplicate output. e.g., "word1 word2" appears more than 1 time. However it will be easy to fix.