# Find all possible subarrays of an array and return it as a string

Tags: java, arrays

This was an interview problem and I'm curious about it.

For example, if you were given: `{1,2}`, You would expect:

```
[[1], [2]], [[1, 2]]
```

If you are given: `{7,3,5}`, you would expect:

```
[[7], [3], [5]],[[7, 3], [5]], [[7], [3, 5]], [[7, 3, 5]].
```

Order does not matter, as long as you include everything. How would you guys solve this?

I already tried making an arraylist of arraylists, and appending each list to a final string. Interviewer pushed me to solve part of this recursively, but I guess making the sublists doesn't have to be recursive, so I figure just adding everything together would be recursive.

Comment: Well if he told you to use recursion it was probably easier that way, I'll think a bit about it and post back if I figure it out.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640034/calculating-all-of-the-subsets-of-a-set-of-numbers

Comment: Also this: http://www.ideserve.co.in/learn/generate-all-subsets-of-a-set-recursion

Comment: Instead of generating all possible subsets it should only generate adjacent subsets